# Increment Dynamic Offset Size

Tags: inkscape

Is there any way to change dynamic offset size other than using the handle? I'd like to be able to create uniform dynamic 5px outside of the original shape for multiple.

I'm looking for something similar to the *Offset Path* dialog box in illustrator.

Comment: I haven't found a numeric way to do that in Inkscape. Which is a bit of a bummer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inkscape does not yet have a GUI option to numerically input and modify the size of the offset. For now, you can easily adjust the offset numerically using the built-in XML Editor:

1. Select the dynamic offset
2. open menu 'Edit > XML Editor…'
3. change the value of the attribute '**inkscape:radius**' to the desired number of px

Comment: This works. Not extremely convenient, but I'm glad it's possible. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the XML Editor.  As a web designer, I think it's awesome. I **<3** Inkscape!

Comment: I'm finding that the value entered and the offset created differ by a factor of 8X. Is this a bug or is there some offset multiplier I'm unaware of?