# Fastest Path Offsetting Method in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path

I am looking for the quickest way to offset the below path inward a specific distance:

[image: Path to Offset]

So that it looks like this:

[image: Offset Path]

This is very easy in AutoCAD using its *Offset* command where you specify the desired offset distance, select the line or poly line you would like to offset, and then either drag the cursor outside or inside the line or poly line to offset it outward or inward respectively.

What would be the quickest way to do this in Inkscape? Thus far I am having to use circles, rectangles and guides to create an offset copy of the original path, and then use the Path Division command to punch it through the original path like this:

[image: My attempt]

As you can see, this is a very, very lengthy procedure. Surely there must be quicker and easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You could try this method.

1. Draw a circle and a triangle with no stroke set, only a fill. Make sure the triangle is under the circle
2. Select both shapes
3. Click *Path > Difference*
4. Remove the fill
5. Apply a thick black stroke, adjust the stroke width as desired
6. Click *Path > Stroke to Path* - if you wish to convert the stroke to outlines.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Select your shape.
2. Duplicate (<kbd>ctrl-D</kbd>).
3. Inset (<kbd>ctrl-(</kbd>) (or dynamic offset, or shrink).
4. Select both original and offset.
5. Difference (<kbd>ctrl- -</kbd>).

Comment: See also: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6419/increment-dynamic-offset-size